# Library not found in Jupyter notebook after installing them using pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-3.8

I have installed `lxml` and pillow using `pip install lxml` and `pip install pillow` and `cmd` is showing that I have successfully installed `lxml` and pillow but on importing `lxml` and pillow in jupyter notebook, it is saying that `library not found`: [image]

jupyter notebook:-[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Make sure you are in the same python environment and restart your jupuyter kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is asked so often all the time. With variations in the use of PyCharm as well. My recommendation for using Jupyter Notebook is to install any package within the notebook itself. In your case, create a cell containing:

```py
!pip install lxml
!pip install pillow
```

After the installation is complete, you can safely remove it. You only need to install them once. You see? As simple as that. So, you are no longer need to think of using a different environment. It's easier if you are still a beginner. Then start learning all about the Python environment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html and of course, not forget to mention about operating system path in case you have multiple version of Python (from Anaconda, the Microsoft Store, and Python official installer).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my problem was different and it is solved now. I deleted the lib from the main python and now it is working in jupyter notebook. Though I don't know how but it is working fine. You can tell why it is working now.!

Comment: Well, I don't know either. You seem to have installed both packages for your Python 3.9 installation, but have opened Jupyter Notebook on your Anaconda. So, I can only tell that you were using a different interpreter.